# Numerical Analysis Gauss Elimination Question

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to solve this question but I'm stuck. Can you help me?

Find approximate solutions of the following system using Gauss Elimination with partial pivoting.
Use 4 significant digits in all process. Apply rounding if you need. Calculate absolute and relative errors for each solutions.

\begin{align}
9x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 − 5x_4 &=37 \\
4 x_2 − 3 x_3 + x_4 &= 2  \\
−3 x_1 + 4 x_2 − 2 x_4 &=8\\
2 x_1 − 3 x_2 + 5 x_3 + x_4 &=0
\end{align}

Exact Solution:
$x_1 = 2, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 1, x_4 = −3$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you please add what you have done and where you are having issues? Here is a similar problem as an example: https://www.rajgunesh.com/resources/downloads/numerical/gaussianelimination.pdf.

Comment: What is *partial* pivoting for you? Are only row permutations allowed? Have you already seen or solved a similar problem, including error estimates, possibly only in 3 variables?